# Wireless Mic & Line Signals

Tags: wireless, line-level

Hello,
Is it possible to transmit a STEREO LINE signal through a wireless mic system.
Im using the Sennheiser ew 100 G3 system. 
I can actually send/receive successfully the signal but my problem is that I can only hear the received signal in one channel...

Please advise or shed some light on the subject if you know, much thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi
Would be great if it were possible, but as far as I know the output from the receiver is mono and there is no way of getting a stereo signal from it.

You would need to look into the Sennheiser IEM systems as these are stereo.

Comment: Ah, actually this would be best solution for the director's and script supervisor's audio split, just need to find an extra $1000 dollars per unit for the sound cart budget. lol Thanks mate, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Im pretty sure the feed is summed to send wirelessly. But you can always use two TXU / RXU and make it stereo the long way.